# MassTransit start after stop

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using masstransit 3.5.7 nuget over rabbitmq.
I need to support start/stop functionality (start after stop).

**How to do it correctly?**

Currently, I implement it like this:

```
private IBusControl _busControl;

public async Task Start()
{
    if(_busControl == null)
    {
        InitBus();
    }

    if (_busControl != null)
    {
        var busBundle = await _busControl.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        BusReady busReady = await busBundle.Ready;

        bool isStarted = IsBusStarted();

        if(!isStarted)
            throw new Exception("Message bus stopped");                
    }
}


public async Task Stop()
{
    if (_busControl != null)
    {
        await _busControl.StopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        bool isStarted = IsBusStarted();

        if (isStarted)
            throw new Exception("Message bus not stopped");

        _busControl = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Function `IsBusStarted` also used in other places - I need to know what current status of masstransit.

```
private bool IsBusStarted()
{
    if (_busControl == null)
        return false;

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = _busControl.GetType().GetField("_busHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var busBundle = fieldInfo.GetValue(_busControl);

     if (busBundle == null)
         return false;

     PropertyInfo prop = busBundle.GetType().GetProperty("Stopped");
     MethodInfo getter = prop.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);

     return !(bool)getter.Invoke(busBundle, null);            
 }
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to implement, why not just bus.Start(); and bus.Stop(); ?

Comment: start after stop - mass transit comment: _"Once the bus has been started, it cannot be started again, even after is has been stopped."_  From here: [https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/IBusControl.cs#L23](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/IBusControl.cs#L23). So, I'm not sure.

Comment: why do you want to stop the bus?

Comment: Let's say we have internal problem (may be problems with s3 connectivity or something else). In this case we want to stop consuming events.

Comment: In that case, stop the bus, discard the instance, and use the same factory code to create a new one.

Comment: Thank You Chris Patterson, another question about my IsBusStarted() function... It's looks complicated, may be there are other way to know if masstransit not Stopped?